# Evince can't open PDF files anymore

Tags: libraries, evince

I always get this error when I try to open pdf files with evince:

```
error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.44: invalid ELF header
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Bug report ? Update evince ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I did an update. Okular can't open PDF files also.

Comment: I also reinstalled poppler-utils. It did not help.

Comment: you better reinstall libpoppler44

Comment: I’m running ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @solsTiCe It didn't help. Another problem: software-center and some other programs won't start.

Comment: You have something strange going on. If you didn't do any manual tweak to the package system (using `apt-get` or similar commands found in internet with sudo), I would *a)* backup your data *b)* check your backup and *c)* `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall  libpoppler44`. And keep and eye on your disk.

Comment: @Rmano It didn't help. Looks like the file system is damaged. Yesterday, the system crashed. This is probably the reason. I didn't do anything special. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Difficult to say. Seems failing RAM or disk... Try to run the memory tester at boot, or search here for SMART and check the disk status.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The RAM and SSD are fine. Flash (Firefox) was probably the reason for the crash.